# How to handle client credit card information for vendor

Tags: encryption, paypal, stripe-payments, payment, credit-card

I am working on an application that require handle of credit card information, would be greatly appreciate if anyone can offer advice.

Basically we partner with 3rd party vendors, when customer place order through us, we will need to send the 3rd party vendor their credit card information to so they can process the payment,  we want to expedite the service for our customer, so they don't have to enter their credit card everytime they make the purchase.  Any suggestion on how to save their credit card info? (I had look into stripe, they can save our customer credit card info, but will not able to give back the full credit card number).

What I have in mind is when customer save they credit card number in our end, we will swap their cc number then encrypt it to save in the db.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: You'd need to be PCI certified to be allowed to handle card data, which is a long and costly process and not a realistic options for most people. Part of the value of Stripe and other card processors is that they greatly ease this burden by providing a technical means to process payments without your server ever seeing the card data. I haven't used them myself, but it sounds like [Spreedly](https://www.spreedly.com/) may be a good fit for your needs!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look at is called Reference Transactions.  These work with both Express Checkout and Payments Pro.

In either case, you process the original authorization / sale transaction, and then you can use the DoReferenceTransaction API to process future payments.

DoReferenceTranscation only requires you to pass in the transaction ID of the original transaction you did and the new amount you want to charge.  It uses the payment information that PayPal has saved on their servers to process the payment accordingly.

This way you are never saving any card details on your own server at all, and PCI compliance is much easier to deal with.

It's essentially the same thing Stripe and others do, but they call it a Vault and PayPal calls it Reference Transactions.

PayPal's new REST API actually does call it a vault, and it's identical to what the others do.

So PayPal has multiple ways to handle it depending on your development preferences.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Will check in to that